# Show that $M_1$ is not a generating set of $\mathbb R^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have a set of vectors, $M_1$ which is defined as the following:
$$M_1:=[\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}]$$
I have to show that $M_1$ isn't a generating set of $\mathbb R^3$, even though it's linearly independent. My initial idea was that, because 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}≠a\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+ b \cdot\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
therefore $M_1$ isn't a generating set of $\mathbb R^3$. However I would like to know if there is any other way to show that $M_1$ is not a generating set of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Generating set of what? $\mathbb R^3$? If so, then your approach is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible that two vectors generate $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, since $dim(\mathbb{R}^{3})=3$ and the dimension of the span of two vectors can be $0$, $1$ or $2$, depending on the vectors you have. In order to find a "$\mathbb{R}^{3}$ generator", you'll have to find three linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 1):

$M_1$ contains only two vectors. So $\mathrm{Vect}(M_1)$ is at most of dimension $2$. Then it cannot be $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

If $M_1$ were a generating set for $\mathbb R^3$ then $\operatorname{dim}\mathbb R^3\le2$, which is false.